# How to fix “Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS” error?

Tags: sql, exists

My query is as follows, and contains a subquery within it:

```
select a.bill_prvdr_acct_id, a.acct_id, a.bill_prvdr_acct_strt_dt, a.bill_prvdr_acct_end_dt
from xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history a
where a.acct_id in 
(select acct_id, count(*)
from xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history 
group by acct_id
having count(*) > 1)
```

and i get the error message "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: get rid of count(*) as a select value.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Given the structure of your query, window functions are probably an easier method to do what you want:

```
select a.bill_prvdr_acct_id, a.acct_id, a.bill_prvdr_acct_strt_dt, a.bill_prvdr_acct_end_dt
from (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by acct_id) as cnt
      from xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history a
     ) a
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Count(*)` is not necessary in the `SELECT` clause of the subquery, only in the `HAVING` clause - the following should work:

```
select a.bill_prvdr_acct_id, a.acct_id, a.bill_prvdr_acct_strt_dt, a.bill_prvdr_acct_end_dt
from xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history a
where a.acct_id in 
(select acct_id
from xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history 
group by acct_id
having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is due to multiple columns selection in subquery.

You cannot select more than one column in `subquery` when you use `IN` operator in `where` clause.

As mentioned in error use `EXISTS` or remove the `count(*)` from `subquery` which is not needed

```
SELECT a.bill_prvdr_acct_id,
       a.acct_id,
       a.bill_prvdr_acct_strt_dt,
       a.bill_prvdr_acct_end_dt
FROM   xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history b
               WHERE  a.acct_id = B.acct_id
               GROUP  BY acct_id
               HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

Or do a `Inner Join`

```
SELECT a.bill_prvdr_acct_id,
       a.acct_id,
       a.bill_prvdr_acct_strt_dt,
       a.bill_prvdr_acct_end_dt
FROM   xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT acct_id
                   FROM   xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history b
                   GROUP  BY acct_id
                   HAVING Count(*) > 1) B
               ON a.acct_id = B.acct_id
```

Answer (score 0):

TO simplify everything run your queries independently first to make sure you return one column:

```
select acct_id
from xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history 
group by acct_id
having count(*) > 1
Above you are returning the acct_id
```

if it brings back the desired results include it in the main query:

```
SELECT a.bill_prvdr_acct_id,
       a.acct_id,
       a.bill_prvdr_acct_strt_dt,
       a.bill_prvdr_acct_end_dt
FROM   xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history a
WHERE  a.acct_id IN (select acct_id
from xxxx_snapshot.dbo.bill_prvdr_acct_history 
group by acct_id
having count(*) > 1)
```

In that way it will be easy to confirm if the subquery return a single column and the desired results and linking it to the main query will make it easy if there is a problem in the main query